# TFS: Query Tasks by their parents conditions

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

We have a hierarchy that User Stories are parents of Tasks (dont know if is the standard).

I need a query to show all Tasks that their parents match some conditions, but I only want the child tasks.

All my tries show both (parents and childs) or only de childs but without parents conditions...
My best approach is this scree shot, but I dont want to see parents items:
[image]

Comment: What are you using the results for?

Comment: I use this query in a dashboard,  displaying the number of tasks with these conditions,  but this counter is counting their parents,  and the number is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Because you only care about showing this on the dashboard, I will recommend you try using the [Query Tile Pro](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mskold.mskold-Query-Tile-PRO).  It will let you show sums of either parents or children for the returned query results.

**Configuration:**

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: I don't only care about showing in the Dashboard, because we use the query tiles as well as links to the query results. However, I will try the extension you recommend. I'll let you know.

Comment: This extension is very useful and it shouldn't be an extension, it should come as a standard addon, but the only problem I see is that is a Preview version, and I don't know if it will be a paid one in the future... Can you shed light on it, @Matt ;)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really sure.  I had installed it a while back and it didn't have the preview tag on it.  In one of the QA comments it looks like the author might consider a free/paid version if they take it out of preview.